# Fortran 95 - Transferring arrays between modules

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran95

I am having a problem transferring arrays between modules and the main program. The module and the main program compile perfectly fine using **gfortran**. However, when executing the .exe file windows encounters a problem and has to close. This only seems to occur when the array is of an unknown size (and its size has to be allocated). I have included a small section of code that illustrates the problem:

**How it works:**
 The user is asked for an integer 'i' which defines the size of the square matrix. This integer is passed to the module function which creates the matrix and returns it to the main program. The matrix is then printed to the screen.

The main program in one file:

```
program main1
use module1
implicit none
integer :: i
real,allocatable :: a(:,:)

write(*,*)'Input the size of the square matrix'
read(*,*)i

allocate(a(i,i))
a = function1(i)

write(*,*) 'The square matrix a='
write(*,*) a

deallocate(a)
end program main1
```

and the module in a separate file:

```
module module1

contains 
function function1(i)
real, allocatable,dimension(:,:) :: function1
integer :: i  

allocate(function1(i,i))
function1 = 1.0

deallocate(function1)
end function function1
end module
```

Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 4):

You are deallocating your `function1` array before the function can return it to the main program. Eliminate the `deallocate(function1)` line and it works perfectly.

Well, not quite perfectly, if you want a square matrix output. You should have the write statement as

```
  do j=1,i
     write(*,*) a(:,j)
  enddo
```

to have the output as something like

```
  1.000  1.000  1.000
  1.000  1.000  1.000
  1.000  1.000  1.000
```

Note that if you are concerned about `function1` taking up memory space, write a subroutine that deallocates it and call it immediately after setting `a=function1(i)`

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence, it seems to suggest that the array allocated inside `function1` is copied to `a`.  My understanding is that after the call to `function1` the array allocated by the function is accessible as the variable `a`, `function1` isn't taking up extra memory.

Comment: I thought that because he is allocating an array there, that it would require memory to do so. I suppose, then, that this is not the case?

Comment: As I (and one other so far !) understand the situation the function returns an allocation of memory to the calling routine which calls the allocated memory `a`.  There is only one allocation of memory.

Comment: I understand now. Good to know for the future. Thanks!

Comment: For the posted code (ignoring the erroneous deallocate) there are two allocations - one for each ALLOCATE statement.  The allocation for the function result is automatically deallocated when the assignment statement containing the function reference completes (i.e. "after execution of the innermost executable construct containing the reference").  The assignment "proper" just copies the value from the function result to a.  Compilers may be clever behind the scenes to avoid pointless memory operations, but the observable result to a standard conforming program has to be "as-if" this behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

@Kyle's answer points out the problem which causes your program to crash.  But there's another subtle issue with your code you should be aware of, though it stops short of being an  outright bug.

If you have an up-to-date compiler, and the right options set, then the allocation statement in your calling code is unnecessary.  That is, you don't need to allocate the variable `a` prior to calling `function1`, Fortran will automatically allocate `a` to the size of whatever `function1` returns.  The compiler option depends, of course, on which compiler you use.  You may need to engage Fortran 2003 semantics or automatic allocation of lhs variables or something similar.

This is an issue you should be aware of because, if you do use automatic allocation (or if your compiler implements it by default), assigning the result of the call to `function1` to `a` will re-allocate `a`.

Comment: You are absolutely right in that the allocate statement is superfluous, but *re*allocation only happens if the size of the lhs (or deferred length parameter or dynamic type, when appropriate) does not match.  Otherwise you can break F95 code.